# Laravel: Convert QueryBuilder to Eloquent:ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How to return, with eloquent, all files where column `deleted_at` is null. I can access the value of `deleted_at` like this `$media->model['deleted_at']`

**In controller I return $files to the view.**

```
$files = $media->paginate(3);
```

**In my view, code below give me empty `<iframe>` if file is deleted.**

```
@foreach ($files as $media)
    @if(is_null($media->model['deleted_at']))
       @php($id = $media->model['id'])
       @php($file_name = $media->model['document_file'][0]['file_name'])
       <iframe style="width: 500px; height: 700px;" src="{{ asset("storage/$id/$file_name") }}"></iframe>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**With QueryBuilder I can do it like this, but how can make the same with eloquent.**

```
$file = DB::table('media')
    ->join('files', 'media.model_id', '=', 'files.id')
    ->select('model_id', 'file_name')
    ->where('deleted_at', '=',null)
    ->paginate(3);
```

Comment: have you defined the relationship between media and file model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a Scout package that has a `withTrashed()` function to retrieve none deleted and soft deleted if you only want the trashed you could use the `onlyTrashed()` function.

```
$files = Media::has('files')->withTrashed()->get();
```

Source: [Laravel Soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent query

```
$file = Media::whereHas('files', function($query) {
   $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
})->get();
```